# 2 different fonts in Wordpress Title PHP?

Tags: php, css, wordpress, fonts, title

I'm using Wordpress with plugins "Wordpress SEO".
I would like to put 2 different fonts in my Title.
example : Core Events Ireland; 'Core Events' in blue, and 'Ireland' in red.
How can I make that by plugins or PHP ? 
Does it work in header.php ?

I think it's in this line :

```
<h1 class="site-title">
  <a href="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>" rel="home">
    <?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?>
  </a>
</h1>
```

Can you tell me if I'm right, and if that doesn't make error with my plugins Wordpress SEO ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to add some structure to your header, so could not use the bloginfo function directly.

```
<h1 class="site-title">
    <a href="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>" rel="home">
    <span class="title-front">Core Events</span> <span class="title-back">Ireland</span>
    </a>
</h1>
```

You can then style .title-front and .title-back any way you want, e.g. color.

This should not interfere with WordPress SEO, because you are not modifying any of the SEO related tags, but just changing the look of the header.